# coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled not working with AGP 8.30

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jdk-desugaring

I recently updated my project to AGP 8.3.0.
And since then I am getting errors:

`Dependency ':x' requires core library desugaring to be enabled for :y.`

I have `coreLibraryDesugaring` enabled,
Groovy:

```
compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
```

I am using `com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4`. All worked before AGP upgrade (8.0.0)

I tried updating desugar lib (this is the latest version), looking for issue on Internet etc

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an obsolete AGP 4.0 property. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring), this should be:

```
compileOptions {

    // For AGP 4.1+
    isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am using Groovy. My approach should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I posted issue in Google issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/329346764

The solution seems to be enabling coreLibraryDesugaring in both modules (that was not required before)